# Can't fadeOut div element with AJAX

Tags: mysql, ajax, row

I can't understand why I can't fade out div element. I'm trying to delete mysql entry, delete function working fine when I reload a page entry dissapears, but I need that entry dissapear without page refresh. tried to creat new empty div and fade out it after entry deletion, worked fine.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("a[id^='delete']").click(function() {
        var numrow = $(this).attr("id");
        numrow = numrow.substr(6);
        var eil = 'id=' + numrow;
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'trinti.php',
                data: eil,
                success: function() {
                    numrowas = "#d"+numrow;
                    $(numrowas).fadeOut();
                }
            });
    });
});
</script>
<?php
require_once('db.php');
if (isset($_GET['list'])) {
$query = "SELECT * FROM zinutes";
mysql_query("SET NAMES 'UTF8'");
$uzklausa=mysql_query($query);
$i = 1;
while($lauk = mysql_fetch_array($uzklausa)){
$r = $lauk['id'];
echo '<div id="d$r">'.$i++.'. Name: '.$lauk['name'].' Message: '.$lauk['message'].' <a href="#" id="delete'.$r.'">Delete</a></div>';
}
}
?>
```

Comment: did you check "numrowas", wheather it's true or not?

Comment: tried to print ir. Got value #d139,  139 is my deleted entry id.

Answer (score 0):

try to do the fading from complete: block.

```
   $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: 'trinti.php',
                    data: eil,
                    success: function() {


                    }
                    complete: function() {
                       numrowas = "#d"+numrow;
                       $(numrowas).fadeOut();
                    }
                });
```